# How do I setup Hyper-V internet access to my virtual machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

We recently switched offices, and are having trouble setting up our Server.  It's a Windows 2008 machine using Hyper V.

One of our virtual machines uses Team Foundtation Server.  It needs to access the internet to activate and unfortunately we don't know how to give Hyper-V's virtual machines internet access.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Virtual Network Manager on the hyper V box, select the physical NIC that you're using in the properties for each VM's network connection.  The connection type will need to be set to "External" to allow the VMs access to the network as if they were "physically" plugged in.

At that point you can treat them as directly attached.

Comment: Also make sure Allow management operating systems to share this network adapter is ticked if in a single NIC environment

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the settings for the vm. A network adapter should be set to the nic that accesses your local network